# Slug URL not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to setup Slug urls in a Django project. I keep getting a 404 error and can not find what I am missing. I have done this several times before but for some reason I must missing something.

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Pages(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="Add Title Here")
    content = models.TextField(default="Add Content Here")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    seo_title = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="Add Title Here")
    seo_description = models.CharField(max_length=160, default="Add Seo Description")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'title')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_page", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, Http404

# Create your views here.
from .models import Pages

def Single(request, slug):
    try:
        page = get_object_or_404(Pages, slug=slug)
        context = {'page': page}
        template = 'pages/page_detail.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
    except:
        raise Http404
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.Single, name='single_page'),
]
```

Comment: You have an unconditional except in your view that raises a 404. I'd recommend that you at least `except Exception as e:` and then log the exception details. At present, just about any error in your view or model is going to throw a 404. May as well see what's actually happening.

Comment: What is the value of `slug` received in the view?

Comment: and view names must be lower case!

Comment: @alecxe content of slug shouldn't matter much for this question, but it would be whatever path param is captured by the `(?P<slug>[\w-]+)`

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman yeah, I hope looking at what `slug` actually is might just give the OP a clue what is going on..

Comment: @alecxe valid point.

Comment: When i access the slug through the shell I get the proper slug. I think it is a request issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help. I found the issue with some help from @vastlysuperiorma

Views.py

```
def single(request, slug):
try:
    page = get_object_or_404(Pages, slug=slug)
    context = {'page': page}
    template = 'pages/page_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
except Pages.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```